# Why does electron/positron pair production form a fractal?

Tags: particle-physics, mathematical-physics, pair-production, fractals

The wikipedia page for electron/positron pair production from photons has a weird section titled "aestheticity", which says that the symettry of the phenomenon meets the definition of a fractal, but is very short and doesn't cite anything.

Is this correct? If so, how does it meet the definition of a fractal?

Wikipedia link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#aestheticity

Comment: It's possible that this part of the wikipedia article is not reliable, as it doesn't cite any information and as far as I can tell does not make sense. An expert may be able to give a better assessment, though.

Comment: As of now the part you mention has been removed.